# Network is unreachable when executing bash script

Tags: python, bash, shell, proxy

I need to automate these steps

```
apt-get install python3
apt-get install python3-pip
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
neo4j_library/create3.sh
python3 -m venv TMD_SAT/TMD
source TMD_SAT/TMD/bin/activate
pip install wheel 
pip install -r TMD_SAT/requirements.txt
```

So I decided to make a install.sh that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get install python3
apt-get install python3-pip
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
neo4j_library/create3.sh
python3 -m venv TMD_SAT/TMD
source TMD_SAT/TMD/bin/activate
pip install wheel 
pip install -r TMD_SAT/requirements.txt
```

But virtual env is not created correctly because wheel and requirements are not installed.
Log i get by executing sudo ./install.sh

```
chain@tmdprod:~$ sudo ./install.sh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0eb42e3820>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/virtualenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0eb42e3100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/virtualenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0eb42e3970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/virtualenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0eb42e3a60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/virtualenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0eb42e3af0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/virtualenv/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for virtualenv
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbe632c5bb0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/wheel/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbe632c51f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/wheel/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbe632c5670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/wheel/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbe632c5790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/wheel/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbe632c5340>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/wheel/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f495777cac0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4957722280>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f49577220d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4957722310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4957722040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/click/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement click==7.1.1 (from -r TMD_SAT/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for click==7.1.1 (from -r TMD_SAT/requirements.txt (line 1))
```

But if I execute each line one by one venv is correctly built.

```
chain@tmdprod:~$ sudo apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
chain@tmdprod:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
chain@tmdprod:~$ python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.4)
chain@tmdprod:~$ python3 -m venv TMD_SAT/TMD
chain@tmdprod:~$ source TMD_SAT/TMD/bin/activate
(TMD) chain@tmdprod:~$ pip install wheel
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.36.2
(TMD) chain@tmdprod:~$ pip install -r TMD_SAT/requirements.txt
Collecting click==7.1.1
  Using cached click-7.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting Flask==1.1.1
  Using cached Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting Flask-Caching==1.9.0
  Using cached Flask_Caching-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Collecting Flask-Cors==3.0.8
  Using cached Flask_Cors-3.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting gunicorn==20.0.4
  Using cached gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0
  Using cached itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==2.11.1
  Using cached Jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
Processing ./.cache/pip/wheels/19/0c/3d/a00086b65374e34750cad316314fbe3efed3cad2650e7b37ca/neo4j-4.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
  Using cached psycopg2_binary-2.8.6-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
Collecting pytz==2019.3
  Using cached pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Collecting PyYAML==5.3
  Using cached PyYAML-5.3.tar.gz (268 kB)
Collecting six==1.14.0
  Using cached six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting virtualenv==15.1.0
  Using cached virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting Werkzeug==1.0.0
  Using cached Werkzeug-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Collecting xlrd==1.2.0
  Using cached xlrd-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in ./TMD_SAT/TMD/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gunicorn==20.0.4->-r TMD_SAT/requirements.txt (line 5)) (44.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyYAML
  Building wheel for PyYAML (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for PyYAML: filename=PyYAML-5.3-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=44228 sha256=b39b70d33f2d00af9dc4f74a0827998093e460d4e3bf8e181048a31efa025134
  Stored in directory: /home/chain/.cache/pip/wheels/e4/94/ec/65e430f66fda7a86c08f61ce59455581adc269a65881b4ffeb
Successfully built PyYAML
Installing collected packages: click, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Flask, Flask-Caching, six, Flask-Cors, gunicorn, pytz, neo4j, psycopg2-binary, PyYAML, virtualenv, xlrd
Successfully installed Flask-1.1.1 Flask-Caching-1.9.0 Flask-Cors-3.0.8 Jinja2-2.11.1 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 PyYAML-5.3 Werkzeug-1.0.0 click-7.1.1 gunicorn-20.0.4 itsdangerous-1.1.0 neo4j-4.2.1 psycopg2-binary-2.8.6 pytz-2019.3 six-1.14.0 virtualenv-15.1.0 xlrd-1.2.0
```

Why? And how can I solve?

Answer (score 2):

I solved by adding

```
export http_proxy=http://proxyip:proxyport
export https_proxy=http://proxyip:proxyport
```

to my install.sh script.
I don't understand why those variables were not recognized when executing the script even if in .bashrc were exported.